# Verify the limit $\lim_{x\to 1} 3^x=3$ with the delta-epsilon definition

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I would like to know if my answer is correct. I have to verify that
$$
\forall\varepsilon>0\quad\exists\delta(\varepsilon, x_0)
\quad
:
\quad
\big(
   x\in(x_0-\delta(\varepsilon, x_0),x_0+\delta(\varepsilon, x_0))\setminus\{      x_{0}\} 
   \quad\Longrightarrow\quad 
   f(x)\in(l-  \varepsilon,l+\varepsilon)
\big).
$$
In our case $l=3$, $x_0=1$ and $f(x)=3^x$.
Hence, starting from
$$
 -\varepsilon<(3^x-3)<\varepsilon
$$
we get
$$
 -\varepsilon<3(3^{x-1}-1)<\varepsilon
$$
and so
$$
 1-\frac{\varepsilon}{3}<3^{x-1}<1+\frac{\varepsilon}{3}.
$$
Now, considering $\varepsilon<3$, we can pass to the logarithm, obtaining
$$
 \log_3\big(1-\frac{\varepsilon}{3}\big)<x-1<\log_3\big(1+\frac{\varepsilon}{3}\big).
$$
and in this case we can choose
$$
   \delta(\varepsilon,1)=
   \min\Big(\log_3\big(1+\frac{\varepsilon}{3}\big), \left|\log_{3}\big(1-\frac{\varepsilon}{3}\big)\right|\Big).
$$
Finally, if $\varepsilon\geqslant3$ we obtain
$$
 0<3^{x-1}<2
$$
and hence
$$
   x-1<\log_3(2)
$$
and we can set $\delta(\varepsilon,1)=\log_3(2)$.
Summaring
$$
\delta(\varepsilon,1)
=
\begin{cases}
\min\Big(\log_{3}\big(1+\frac{\varepsilon}{3}\big),\left|\log_{3}\big(1-\frac{\varepsilon}{3}\big)\right|\Big) & \textrm{if }\varepsilon\in(0,3)
\\
\log_{3}(2) & \textrm{if }\varepsilon\geqslant3.
\end{cases}
$$
Thanks to everyone who will check my solution.